# How to include additional directories when configuring makefiles

Tags: linux, makefile, configure, geany, geany-plugin

I'm trying to compile geany-plugins-1.28. The debugger plugin (the only one I need) gives the error:

```
debug.c:53:21: fatal error: vte/vte.h: No such file or directory
#include <vte/vte.h>
```

Clearly it needs to know where this file is located to compile. I found the vte.h file in the src directory of the main program geany-1.28. When running

```
sudo ./configure cflags=-I/home/pi/Desktop/geany-1.28/src
```

I get the same error about the missing header later trying to compile the debugger plugin.

I ran

```
./configure --help
```

to get all the flag options. The output is [here](http://pastebin.com/iZUkW6C3)

How do I get this to configure correctly so that it compiles. I need to compile the debugger version 1.28 myself because apt only installs 1.24 which I think has a bug because it crashes when I run my code with the error:

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.execpthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38358706/2915834) stated, vte.h is not the file you are looking for. Install libvte(-dev) package on your system and rerun configure.

Just for the record: vte.h on Geany is a dummy to allow Geany to kind of dynamical enable vte or disable it depending on vte is installed on the system or not.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I don't know how I didn't come across this sooner.

Answer (score 2):

`CFLAGS` is case-sensitive environment variable, so you should set it before running configure, not try to pass it as a command line argument. This variant:

```
$ export CFLAGS=-I/home/pi/Desktop/geany-1.28/src
$ ./configure
```

leaves CFLAGS set for current shell until you leave it. While this:

```
$ CFLAGS=-I/home/pi/Desktop/geany-1.28/src ./configure
```

sets variable only for current command, i.e. `configure`.

Some other issues:

- You do not need `sudo` to configure and make. It is also unnecessary for `make install` if you set `PREFIX` to a path you have privileges to write to.
- Does plugin's build system also builds all it's dependencies? If not, you may face linker errors a bit later.

Update:

I have tried to build `debugger` plugin and got rid of your error. It seems that `vte.h` coming with Geany is it's intrinsic, while the plugin requires full-featured file from the library. So I just installed `vte` and `vte-devel` from repos. Nevertheless, I got some other unrelated errors coming from Glib. I will not continue my attempts to build all this right now. Hope my effort will be helpful at least a little.

Comment: I just tried this and still got the same error about vte.h not being found. Is CFLAGS even the correct variable to set? I'm new to compiling on Linux.

Comment: ./configure operates recursively creating a makefile for individual plugins. When I compile, I'm only compiling the debugger plugin.

Comment: @Jkallus What is exact path to `vte.h`? If it is `/home/pi/Desktop/geany-1.28/src/vte.h`, you get the error because `#include <vte/vte.h>` with `-I` pointing to `...../src` wants the file in `/home/pi/Desktop/geany-1.28/src/vte/vte.h`. The quick-n-dirty workaround is `ln -s /home/pi/Desktop/geany-1.28/src /home/pi/Desktop/geany-1.28/src/vte`.

Comment: the exact path is /home/pi/Desktop/geany-1.28/src/vte.h

Comment: I ran the command to put vte.h in a new folder "vte". Then reconfigured and tried to compile. Still got the same error